# Safari Extension - Change new tab homepage

Tags: safari

Is it possible to create extension that changes safari homepage? If yes, can someone provide me some guidelines? Maybe some reading material?

Something like this(but for chrome):https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/city-page-today-home-page/omjifaanlgiocfonnjlengeomjfhgklg

Thanks!

**EDIT:** A simple redirect would be okey. When user click's new tab he instantly gets redirected to our site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need to do:
Goto Safari, then choose Preferences, then click General

From there you can set your homepage

Safari, to my knowledge, does not support extensions like those you are looking for, but there is the way to change it.

Hope this helps!

[Apple Support Here](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19286?locale=en_US)

Comment: Yeah, i already knew about that option. Was looking for an option to change the homepage as an extension.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, i think it is not possible to do it in extension.

Comment: Is this still the case or has Apple allowed this?